# Javascript nested scope

Tags: javascript, function, nested

```
var landscape = function() {

  var result = "";

  var flat = function(size) {

    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += "_";
  };

  var mountain = function(size) {

    result += "/";
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += "'"; //this statement comes first so ,"'" should print first 
    result += "\\"; //Then this should print "\"

/*
loop will run 4 times. it should print /'\'\'\' to my understanding.
*/



  };

  flat(3);

  mountain(4);

  flat(6);

  mountain(1);

  flat(1);

  return result;
};

console.log(landscape());
```

Why is this returning :`_ _ _ / ' ' ' ' \\_ _ _ _ _ _/ ' \\ _`

How I think it should return:`_ _ _ / ' \ ' \ ' \ ' \ _ _ _ _ _ _ / ' \ _`

Please help me understand why its returning like that?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't returning a single slash, but according to your code, for mountain, it just adds a "'" for each iteration of the loop. Whenever you don't use the curly bracket notation for the for loop, it only uses the next "line" of code. If you want the desired output, you will have to put the `result += "\\";` inside of curly brackets with the `result += "'";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't return `'\'\'\` because the `\` is only printed after the `for` loop completes.  If curly brackets aren't used with a `for` loop, it will use only the following instruction.  In this case, it will only use the `result += "'"` instruction and not the `result += "\\"` instruction.

So, in words, your mountain(4) function is saying:

1. Add a `/`
2. Add 4 `'`
3. Add a `\`

Comment: "\" its printed in the loop.

Comment: No it isn't.  If there were curly brackets around both statements, it would be.  But as it is written, only the apostrophe is in the loop.

Comment: so what about the second statement result += "\\". why is that not bieng run?

Comment: It's being run once, after the for loop finishes.

Answer (score 4):

The `\` only appear once per `mountain()` because it's not being repeated within the `for` loop.

Loops only use the 1st statement that follows them, similar to doing:

```
for (var count = 0; count < size; count++) {
  result += "'";  // appended for each `count`
}
result += "\\";   // appended once after the loop has completed
```

To achieve the output you're expecting, a block would have to be added around both statements so they repeat together:

```
for (var count = 0; count < size; count++) {
  result += "'";
  result += "\\";
}
```

Comment: @jonathna the code i have on here is exactly from the book and when i run it it gives me this result : ___/''''\______/'\_
But in the code, this comes wihtout the curly on the for loop. Thats why im confused.

Comment: @user3525853 From which book?

Comment: the book is called eloquent javascript 
http://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/preview/03_functions.html
scroll down to nested scope

Comment: @user3525853 I think you may be confused about how the for loop is functioning.  The way it is currently written, it's basically saying "repeat the immediate next statement X amount of times".  The immediate next statement is `result += "'"`.  After the for loop has done that, program execution continues to the next statement, which is `result += "\\"`